# Python - Selenium cancel proxy usage

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I'm using python + selenium to open pages with proxy
So it's like:

```
self.mainBrowser = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=proxy); time.sleep(1)
```

where's

```
myProxy = proxy_ip + ":" + proxy_port
proxy = Proxy({
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,
    'httpProxy': myProxy,
    'ftpProxy': myProxy,
    'sslProxy': myProxy,
    'noProxy': '' # set this value as desired
})
```

I'm reading proxies dynamicly from online list(using selenium too). Some of proxies are broken so I want to take another one and try it. But when I'm opening proxy list with

```
br = webdriver.Firefox(proxy=None)
br.get(proxy_server)
```

It opens with my previous proxy(or maybe cannot connect, because i see no connection error which is same for broken proxies). How can I make it run without proxy?

Answer (score 1):

If `proxy=None` is not working you can try settings it to your localhost with
`String PROXY = "localhost:8080";` or something similar.
Alternatively, you can try to get the list of proxies using a tool that isn't selenium. Maybe with `HttpUrlConnection`?

Comment: You're actually wrong. I looked up in webdriver sources and it's
'    def __init__(self, firefox_profile=None, firefox_binary=None, timeout=30,
                 capabilities=None, proxy=None, executable_path='wires'):'
So None proxy is default.
But thanks for other method I'll try it.

Comment: Yeah me too. That's why I tried suggesting a work-around. proxy=None doesn't actually change anything it just doesn't add the proxy to the capabilities. So I thought maybe giving `localhost` a try would work out. Hopefully it will!

Comment: Localhost just killed my connection entirely. Not my way because you'll have to always find the default port for it (which i failed at).

Comment: Ah well. My low expertise has failed you. Good luck finding the answer!